# Название места возле маркера

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Подскажите, как можно разместить название места сбоку маркера, на которое указывает маркер?
Т.е. на сайт нужно добавить описание места с помощью js
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```
mMap = googleMap;
LatLng hh = new LatLng(50.462505, 30.468507);// Ваша позиция
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hh, 14));
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(hh).title("title").snippet("snipet"));
```

Это если Java-Android.

Comment: нет нужно для вёрстки, где-то было сказано про андроид?

Comment: и вашем коде я не вижу выравнивание текста

Comment: @word, думаю, принцип тот же.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в этом коде нет нигде выравнивания текста. Какой может быть тут принцип, и это совсем разные платформы?

Comment: В вопросе тоже нет ничего про выравнивание текста. Вопрос просто как добавить, ответ - title и snippet. А гугл уж сам как-нибудь пристроит.

Comment: @Qwertiy, покажите пример, как гугл пристроит

Comment: @Qwertiy, если вы не вкурсе, то атрибут title показывает текст при наведении, а мне нужно совсем другое, если вы читали вопрос, мне нужно показывать название сбоку от маркера

Comment: кто-то подскажет?